# Fourier series proving $\sum \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have calculated the Fourier series of $x^4$ in $(-4,4)$  as

$$f(x) = \frac{256}{5} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2048}{\pi^2n^2} \cos(\pi n ) -\frac{12288}{\pi^4n^4} \cos(\pi n )\right)\cos (\frac{\pi n x}{4})$$

I have been asked to use

$$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

to show that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90} $$

Not sure how to go about this any pointers would help.

Comment: i assume you sub it in for the $n^2$ and try to prove that the $n^4$  = the above but not sure how you would prove this

Comment: Plug $x=0$ in the Fourier series. With $x= 4$ you'll get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}$

Comment: how can i plug in 0 and 4? how do you mean? thanks btw

Comment: But if I plug in 0 to that equation I don't seem to get anything

Comment: Have a look at pages 8-9 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) where $\zeta(4)=\frac{2}{5}\zeta(2)^2$ is proved by considering a logarithmic integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^4$ is $C^1$ and has equal values at the endpoints of $[-4,4]$ we have
$$
x^4= \frac{256}{5} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2048}{\pi^2n^2} \cos(\pi n ) -\frac{12288}{\pi^4n^4} \cos(\pi n )\right)\cos \left(\frac{\pi n x}{4}\right)
$$
for $x\in[-4,4]$. Hence, taking $x=4$ we get
$$
\begin{split}
256
&= \frac{256}{5} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2048}{\pi^2n^2} \cos(\pi n ) -\frac{12288}{\pi^4n^4} \cos(\pi n )\right)\cos (\pi n )\\
&= \frac{256}{5} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2048}{\pi^2n^2} -\frac{12288}{\pi^4n^4}\right)\\
&= \frac{256}{5} +  \frac{2048}{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6} -\frac{12288}{\pi^4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}.
\end{split}
$$
And after some simple computations we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}.
$$